# Phonegap BarcodeReader is not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I need some help with implementing the barcode reader plugin into my phonegap application.

I've already added the plugin via cli to my phonegap project. Now there is a plugin folder with the barcodescanner.js inside. I've added "'<'gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />" to my config.xml. And this is my index.html code :

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <script src="plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/www/barcodescanner.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script>
        function scanner() {
            cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
                function(result) {
                    alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                        "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                        "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                        "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
                },
                function(error) {
                    alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
                }
            );
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Scan" onClick="scanner()" />
</body>

</html>
```

If I click on my button the Logcat says, that it cant find cordova.plugins...... Does anyone encountered that issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see reference to `cordova.js` in your source and it's the only cordova-specific file you need to add. Using Cordova 3 CLI the plugins are imported automagically by scripts in cordova.js (no need to add reference to plugin's JS file).

Edit.: BTW don't copy the cordova.js file to your app folders, just use `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` in your html. The file specific to given platform will be placed in the platform's `www` folder during `cordova prepare`.

Comment: Wow.. i was stucking for hours just for an import..  Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Yeah, I've found about auto-importing plugins the hard way too (in my case code was executed twice - once after import from `<script>` tag and once after cordova has imported it by itself). But it's a cool feature once you know it :)